# How to merge two columns of a row just like 'merge and center in excel' in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe for which I need to group/merge/combine two columns in a row. So that the value is same for both the columns.

I have tried multi indexing but it works for the columns not for rows

This is the code for dataframe. I want the sum of both the Score1 and Score2 against Total

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10, 2],['B', 11, 3],['Total', 26, 26]],columns=['Name', 'Score1', 'Score2'])
```

I want the dataframe like below. merge two cells of a row just like 'merge and center' in excel

[image]

Comment: What's the end goal? Pandas doesn't have a merge cells function and centre is for styling only.

Comment: I need to show the total of both the scores together in a cell

Comment: have a look at this https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html it has a section on merge & un-merge.

Comment: It works with a workbook, but when I convert it again into a dataframe it splits with value in one column and NaN in the other

Comment: I need it in dataframe format as I need transform dataframe to html using to_html

Comment: then can you show us your intended output in either a dataframe or html format? you're showing us excel atmo.